# Built-in speakers in my Asus EEE PC 1000H netbook do not work after boot

Tags: 11.10, sound, speakers, audio-jack

*I have to plug and unplug out something into the minijack, and then I am able to hear sound from my speakers. This problem re-occurs everytime I reboot my computer. I am using a Asus EEE PC 1000H, and I have made sure my volume is up.*

*//Additional informations: I created new administrator user, when I log into that user, everything is good. I can hear login sound :). When I shutdown my netbook from old user I got "[orange star "*"]*PulseAudio configured for per user session." error, but when I turn off netbook from that new user, I don't got any error like this.*

Okay, now sound works great, just after logging into my account, don't know how I repaired that, maybe because of creating new account? o0. But I still can't hear login sound. I can hear that sound when login into other account (the new one). And I still have "PulseAudio configured for per user session" warning.

Comment: Can you post your /etc/asound.conf file? In addition what version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: balloons: I don't have that file, It's just don't exist. And I'm using 11.10, before that I was using 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

G G , potentially you messed up your configuration (or something else did), and the default configuration works (aka, a new user). If everything is working for you now I wouldn't make any further changes :-) However, you can reset your users configuration by purging pulseaudio and then reinstalling. This will remove the configurations which are potentially incorrect and put you back to "stock".

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop pulseaudio
```

The second command to install ubuntu-desktop should reinstall the necessary pieces of alsa and pulseaudio (if removed above by the purge). **BE CAREFUL HERE** and take note of the packages your will be asked to remove by purging pulseaudio. Make sure reinstalling ubuntu-desktop pulls everything back in (it should, but ;-) ).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I'll try this, now I'm not hearing boot sound only. So I think I'll wait to 12.04 upgrade, and install it from scratch. I just don't want to take a risk, but maybe if I'll try, are there any pulseaudio *.conf file with pulse config that I can backup?